# How to insert and update after

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql-insert

I have this stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @itWorks nvarchar (39)
SET @itWorks = @dbName + '.' +@tblName

INSERT INTO sampleDatabase.dbo.WorkFlowCopy
       ([ID]
      ,[ActivityDefinitionID]
      ,[ParentID]
      ,[Caption]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ShortDescription]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Order]
      ,[ReferenceNumber]
      ,[ShowOnNavigation]
      ,[Status]

EXEC('SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''SQLOLEDB'',''Data Source=' + @serverName+ ';User ID='+@userID+';Password=' +@password+''').'+@itWorks+' sdb1')

UPDATE sampleDatabase.dbo.WorkFlowCopy 
SET ServerName = @serverName, 
    DBName = @dbName 
WHERE ServerName = NULL AND DBName = NULL
```

That query's function is to insert values from another server into specific database. That's why I used dynamic query. After that insert statement, my columns (ServerName, DBName) in my specific database table will become NULL because I haven't insert any values in it.

So I used `UPDATE` query after for that but it didn't work. "(0 row(s) affected)" Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition is incorrect. `NULL` isn't a value, so don't compare to `NULL` but instead use `IS NULL`

```
/*Change*/
WHERE ServerName = NULL AND DBName = NULL
/*To*/
WHERE ServerName IS NULL AND DBName IS NULL
```

That said, it would be much more efficient to set those values in the previous `SELECT` statement. You should in any case change `SELECT *` to explicitly specify column values. Your current code is at risk of breaking due to schema changes. So Add ServerName and DBName to your `INSERT` and change the dynamic `SELECT` as follows:

```
EXEC('SELECT  ID,
        ActivityDefinitionID,
        ParentID,
        ...,
        Status,
        '+@serverName+',
        '+@dbName'
FROM ...')
```